# k_mean.fit returns ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: arrays, image, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to pass through image feature representations, which have been saved as a list of arrays, to cluster through kmeans.

```
features_list = []
features = np.asarray(features_list)  

features_flat = features.reshape((features.shape[0], -1))
k_means = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=10, n_jobs=-1)
k_means.fit(features_flat)
```

where information on features_flat is below:

```
print(features_flat)

Out:[[ array([[[ 0.36470588,  0.32156863,  0.2627451 ,  0.36862745],
    [ 0.36470588,  0.32156863,  0.2627451 ,  0.36862745],
    [ 0.36470588,  0.32156863,  0.2627451 ,  0.36862745],
    ..., 
[ array([[[ 0.19607843,  0.19215686,  0.14117647,  0.30980392],
    [ 0.19607843,  0.19215686,  0.14117647,  0.30980392],
    [ 0.19607843,  0.19215686,  0.14117647,  0.30980392],
    ..., 
    ]]

np.unique(list(map(len, features_flat)))
Out: array([1])
```

I get the following error when running k_means.fit()

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How do I preserve the data in the array while creating the right type of matrix?

Comment: "features_flat" is not flat. it is a list of lists of 3d tensors. Data to KMeans has to be a 2D array - simply process your data so that it is indeed 2 dimensional, specifics depend on what is inside. Since "reshape" did not work, I am suspecting your "features" are of **varied size**, which will cause numpy to just treat each element as some magical object, rather than array which can be resized

Comment: @lejlot My data is 3d since they are representations of color images. Is there a way to keep the color data while converting to 2d?..

Comment: The **dataset** needs to be 2D, not **datapoint**. Your single **point** is 3D, which makes dataset 4D, but it has to be 2D. K-Means does not care about "meaning" of pixels, thus if you want to cluster images you will end up **flattening** them, thus converting your 3D images to 1D flat vectors. What is crucial though is that each image needs to have **the same size**. And I suspect yours are not (otherwise reshape would work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @lejlot

It works with the image representation from this transformation.

[Standardized image size for each image + mapped to grayscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YHZS.png)

I was hoping it would work with the below image representation

[Original image transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw2RG.png)

, but this resolves this particular question.